# Spring Boot HttpSecurity redirect to defaultSuccessUrl even if the role differs

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to make a simple login page with spring boot 2.3.1

```
@Override
 protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
 }

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/",
                        "/home",
                        "/test",
                        "/resources/**"
                )
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/demo").hasAnyRole( "USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/demo")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
        .and().httpBasic();
    }
```

Here is the code from my MyUserDetailsService

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findUserByUserName(userName);

        if (null ==user) {
            throw (new UsernameNotFoundException("no user found!"));
        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getUserAuthority(user.getRoles());

        return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getUserAuthority(Set<Role> userRoles) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> roles = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (Role role : userRoles) {
            roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>(roles);
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

    private UserDetails buildUserForAuthentication(User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(),
                user.getActive(), true, true, true, authorities);
    }
}
```

I have an user in database (demo with role  ADMIN). I don't understand why after I click on the submit button it's make redirect to /demo route. For me the role USER, means to force the login sistem to make the  redirect to "/demo" route only if the form submited match the user, password and the role.

How can i change the "configure" method to allow redirect to demo route only when the credential from login form match the user from database (user, password and role)?

p.s please excuse my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Change

```java
  .antMatchers("/demo").hasAnyRole( "USER")   // <-- is ignored due to later duplication
  .anyRequest().authenticated()
  .and()
  .formLogin()
  .loginPage("/login")
  .defaultSuccessUrl("/demo")
  .permitAll()                                 // <--- permit all for /demo
```

To:

```java
  .anyRequest().authenticated()
  .and()
  .formLogin()
  .loginPage("/login")
  .defaultSuccessUrl("/demo")
  .hasAnyRole( "USER")                       // <-- USER for /demo
```